# How to reformat a laptop when file device inserted has hide and make shortcut?

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, format

What is the best solution for me to reformat a Acer Aspire E14 with Windows 8.1 operating system that only have C Drive and **every time I inserted USB flash drive file has been compressed and put into a shortcuts.** And when I put and use my external hard-drive nothing happen. I never used my DVD/CD ROM because it not working or it's lens has been damage. I try to make a full scan on my laptop using 360 Total Security also nothing happen.

In addition, I try to put my USB flash drive every time my laptop still on its start up and even restarting fast and open configure bot menu but still it open on Windows 8.1 start screen and nothing happen or still the same.

Comment: You have been infected by the Shortcut Virus.

Comment: @DavidPostill. I need a recommendation on how to reformat my laptop if it's making shortcuts for every devices inserted it.

Comment: Insert a read only device :)

Comment: Take out your hard drive and format it in another computer.

Comment: Get your DVD drive fixed.